# populating property with button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I am new to C# and like to know how do i add data from text boxes to a automatic property with a button click

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Comment: "automatic property"? What is that and where is yours?

Comment: its a get set property to send back data from a window with text boxes,, my window has two textboxes to get a Name and Surname and the the button click should send the data of textboxes to the property Name

Comment: Where are the properties defined?

Comment: property is defined in AddName.xaml.cs

Comment: And where is btnOK_Click defined?

Comment: Also in the same .cs as the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply set the value of the `Name` property to the value of the `Text` property of the `TextBox`?:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the data should go through the property to add the data as a new object in the collection

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "should go through the property ..."

Comment: newName is an property that should be populated with the information of the textboxes

Comment: Yes, and I have showed how to set it to the value of the TextBox.

Comment: so if there is multiple textboxes i will say

Comment: name = textbox2.Text just under the first one?

Comment: Yes, of course.